# Can I comment github issue via commit?

Tags: github

We can use 'smart commits' in JIRA to comment for issue also demonstarate how long we worked for this particular issue etc. Can I use this feature for Github Issue, I know we can close issue by typing buzzwords like 'fixes' in front of issue number, but my question is how can I write comment for issue through commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do the same with GitHub, by referencing the issue number in the log message.

For example, if I create a commit with this message:

```
apply solution from #76 to file.cc
```

then the page on GitHub for issue #76 will show a message saying

> *user* pushed a commit to *branch* that referenced this issue on *date*

and show the commit log and sha1 on the next line.